# Parallel in Apache Camel Aggregator

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a Camel route configuration like below:

```
from("seda:logCall?concurrentConsumers=50")
                    .aggregate(header("EXCHANGE_ID"), new CustomAggregator())
                    .completionSize(2)
                    .parallelProcessing()
                    .to("bean:someAdapter?method=someMethod");
```

What I want to achieve is parallel processing all the way down means messages should be processed in parallel by aggregator and bean (after aggregation). However, when I was debugging I saw that aggregate blocks (run in a single thread). Bean processes messages in parallel so it is ok.

How should I configure aggregator to aggregate incoming messages in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
from("seda:logCall?concurrentConsumers=50")
    .threads().executorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
    .aggregate(header("EXCHANGE_ID"), new CustomAggregator())
    .completionSize(2)
    .parallelProcessing()
    .to("bean:someAdapter?method=someMethod");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).